# BrickPi motors rev but don't move robot

Tags: python, raspberry-pi, raspbian

I'm playing around with a BrickPi on the Raspberry Pi.

I'm using Python to control a 4 wheel drive robot. The default program allows you to control it in real time. But I tried to create a program that gives the robot a set route, ie `move forwards 3 seconds then stop` by using the code:

```
def fwd():
    BrickPi.MotorSpeed[fl] = speed  
    BrickPi.MotorSpeed[fr] = speed  
    BrickPi.MotorSpeed[bl] = -speed  
    BrickPi.MotorSpeed[br] = -speed
    BrickPiUpdateValues()



def stop():
    BrickPi.MotorSpeed[fl] = 0  
    BrickPi.MotorSpeed[fr] = 0  
    BrickPi.MotorSpeed[bl] = 0  
    BrickPi.MotorSpeed[br] = 0
    BrickPiUpdateValues()

fwd()
time.sleep(4)
stop()
```

But it just revs up for like a second then instantly stops...
I have the motors setup and assigned elsewhere in the code. And speed is set to 200.

The documentation for the library hasn't been helpful.

How do I make this work?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> But it just revs up for like a second then instantly stops... I have the motors setup and assigned elsewhere in the code. And speed is set to 200.

It looks like this should run at full blast, then stop.  [The BrickPi](http://www.dexterindustries.com/site/?product_cat=brickpi-lego-for-raspberry-pi) firmware has a safety feature that shuts down motors if it doesn't hear from the Raspberry Pi every few seconds.  You might want to change the code to something like this:

```
fwd()
ot = time.time()
while(time.time() - ot < 4):    #running while loop for 3 seconds
    BrickPiUpdateValues()       # Ask BrickPi to update values for sensors/motors
    time.sleep(.1)
stop()
```

The loop on the fourth line calls the code every 100 ms (updates the BrickPi) and keeps the motors alive and running.

And you can see our code examples for [running LEGO Mindstorms motors with the Raspberry Pi here](https://github.com/DexterInd/BrickPi_Python/tree/master/Sensor_Examples).

Hope this helps!